# is it possible to set a working src attribute to a <p> tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make this code work.

```html
<p onmouseover=this.src=http://website.com>test</p>
```

But the this.src part is now loading the website. Is a different attribute that i could add after the onmouseover part to make the

```html
<p>
```

tag load a website? Is there anything similar (supported by the p tag) that i could use?

Comment: now loading the website ( I meant it's not loading the website)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? why can't you use the <a> tag?

Comment: why don't you want to add an `a` tag?

Comment: Do you want to load that website into the p's body?

Comment: I'm trying to do this thing <img src="url.jpg" onmouseover=this.src=http://website.com> but i'd like to do this with a <p> tag.

Comment: Please, can you answer my question.  Do you want to load that website into the p's body?

Comment: use `iframe` with on hove show functionnalit

Answer (score 1):

Just use this : 
`<p onclick="location.href='yourlocation'"></p>`

Comment: this is the right answer you OP's question, however you just shouldn't. use a button or anchor element as best practice.

Comment: @digital-pollution no, this is not what the OP wants to accomplish.

Comment: @Ele yes, i want to load that website into the p's body

Comment: ah ok then you need to use the iframe element (just change the p to iframe)

Comment: @digital-pollution What i was asking was if there's a way to do it without using iframes

Comment: ah ok yes you can but it's a lot more involved, you'd need an xhr request that pulls in the html from the other website and inserts it into your page. but there are a lot of considerations like cross domain security and if there are any scripts required to run for the website you're trying to embed, the answers to this are well beyond the scope of this question. Also note that if the website you are trying to embed does not belong to you then iframe is your only real option.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<p>` tag inside `<a>` tag and there you have the src attribute